# Is there any way to restart my iOS app programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to know if is any method to restart my app programmatically. It's an iOS app and I work with Xcode 12.3 in swift.

Comment: No, there is not.  You can reestablish your starting state but you cannot have the app fully exit and relaunch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no methods available in iOS to restart your application, BUT you could manually reinstantiate initial root `UIViewController` when needed.

---

To reinstantiate root `UIViewController` you could use following *static* functions in your `AppDelegate` class:

```
static func getWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
}

static func resetViewController() {
    let window = getWindow()
    
    let controller = ...  /// Instantiate your inital `UIViewController`
    
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

---

**Note:**

"Restarting" app is a **very uncommon practice** and **should be avoided** in all cases if possible.